# cURL hangs unless using IPv6 with HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, ip, ipv6, curl, ufw

I need to make some cURL requests to a server that doesn't have an ipv6 address, but my machine only seems able to connect when 1) using https, and 2) using ipv6. Other requests hang indefinitely after DNS resolution, before any connection is established.

Would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this.

The machine is running Ubuntu 18.04.4 with curl 7.58.0 and ufw 0.36.

This happens with any domain, but here are some examples with google.com:

```
me@myserver:/$ curl -I4 http://www.google.com --trace-ascii /dev/stdout --no-tcp-nodelay
== Info: Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.com/
== Info:   Trying 142.251.40.100...
*hangs*

me@myserver:/$ curl -I4 https://www.google.com --trace-ascii /dev/stdout --no-tcp-nodelay
== Info: Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
== Info:   Trying 142.251.40.100...
*hangs*

me@myserver:/$ curl -I6 http://www.google.com --trace-ascii /dev/stdout --no-tcp-nodelay
== Info: Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.com/
== Info:   Trying 2607:f8b0:4006:81f::2004...
*hangs*

me@myserver:/$ curl -I6 https://www.google.com --trace-ascii /dev/stdout --no-tcp-nodelay
== Info: Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
== Info:   Trying 2607:f8b0:4006:81f::2004...
== Info: Connected to www.google.com (2607:f8b0:4006:81f::2004) port 443 (#0)
*no problems*
```

I've tried IP whitelisting in UFW, but it doesn't help:

```
me@myserver:/$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    142.251.40.100
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

The machine is running Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Here's the (gently reformatted) output of `curl -V`:

```
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) 
    libcurl/7.58.0 
    OpenSSL/1.1.1d 
    zlib/1.2.11 
    libidn2/2.3.0 
    libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) 
    nghttp2/1.30.0 
    librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: 
    dict file ftp ftps gopher http https 
    imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s 
    rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: 
    AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy
    IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Comment: your UFW rules are all incoming rules, your UFW allows all outgoing anyway - so, it's nothing to do with UFW - perhaps some other firewall between you machine and the internet is responsible

Comment: Can you `traceroute` to the IPv4 address?

Comment: @JaromandaX Good point. Looking through iptables for anything suspicious now.

Comment: @hardillb The box don't have traceroute installed (and can't get apt working with the current network situation). `mtr -6b --tcp google.com` displays nothing, same using `-4`, but `--udp` and icmp packets both go through.

Comment: I think you misunderstood - I meant a physical machine ... like a router, or a firewall

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah, rereading your comment that does make sense. iptables on my machine look clear; I think you're right.